# How can I create nested tree from map input

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, data-structures, nested-loops

Trying to restructure my map in order to see it as a Tree.

data :

```json
{
  "FacebookAPI": [
    "TwitterAPI",
    "TiktokAPI",
    "TeslaAPI"
  ],
  "TeslaAPI": ["TwitterAPI"],
  "TiktokAPI": ["WhatsAppAPI"],
  "BitcoinAPI": [],
  "WhatsAppAPI": [],
  "GoogleAPI": [
    "FacebookAPI",
    "TeslaAPI",
    "TwitterAPI",
    "TiktokAPI"
  ]
}
```

expected output

```json
{
  "GoogleAPI": [
    {
      "FacebookAPI": [
        { "TeslaAPI": { "TwitterAPI": [] } },
        "TwitterAPI",
        { "TiktokAPI": { "WhatsAppAPI": [] } },
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

my goal is to calculate the depth of each parent item :

Example :

**Google calls** :  Facebook + Tesla + Twitter + Tiktok + WhatsAppAPI => depth should be **5**

**Whatsapp calls** :  CryptoEndToEnd => depth should be **1**

can anyone help me out.

Comment: Could you explain how **Google** calls has **WhatsAppAPI** to get depth **5**? Because, the `GoogleAPI` array only has 4 items: `["FacebookAPI", "TeslaAPI", "TwitterAPI", "TiktokAPI"]`.

Comment: hello , I have edited my example  . because TiktokAPI has WhatsAPI . so the total = 5

Comment: From the question: _Whatsapp calls : CryptoEndToEnd => depth should be 1_ --> after the edit, it seems that there is nothing called **CryptoEndToEnd** any more.

Comment: sorry for the delay of my answer . I re-posted my question here with a good examples this time : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72322008/calculate-graph-api-calls